# Simultaneously using accelerometer and gyroscope in Windows phone 8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am trying to simultaneously pull the readings from accelerometer and gyroscope in a windows 8 phone application. To do so, I am invoking a method whenever the value of acceleration changes and then starting my gyroscope inside this method. However, I am not sure if I am reading both the sensors at the same time.
Here is some code.

```
private void UpdateUI(AccelerometerReading accelerometerReading, Gyroscope gyroscope)
    {

        GyroscopeReading gyroCurrentVal = gyroscope.CurrentValue;
        if (lastUpdatedTimeGyro.Equals(DateTimeOffset.MinValue))
        {
            lastUpdatedTimeGyro = gyroCurrentVal.Timestamp;
        }
        else
        {

                rotationRate = gyroCurrentVal.RotationRate;

                 TimeSpan timeSinceLastUpdate = gyroCurrentVal.Timestamp - lastUpdatedTimeGyro;


                Vector3 acceleration = accelerometerReading.Acceleration;
                acceleration.X = Math.Abs(acceleration.X);
```

...

How can I make sure of that?

Comment: Can you add some code? This is a bit vague.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for being vague. I have added some code now.